# "ipcluster nbextension enable" doesn't have subcommand specified

Tags: ipython-parallel

I have ipyparallel 5.3.0. Its official doc, https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel#install, instructs the following:

> To enable the IPython Clusters tab in Jupyter Notebook:

```
ipcluster nbextension enable
```

But I got the following issue hence it didn't work.

```
No subcommand specified. Must specify one of: ['start', 'stop', 'engines'].
```

I did more checks following minrk's tips.

```
$ipcluster --version
5.2.0

$which -a ipcluster
/home/etlolap/anaconda3/bin/ipcluster
/user/bin/cluster

$head -n 1 $(which ipcluster)
#!/home/etlolap/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Everything looks fine though.

Answer (score 1):

For all users with root/admin access :

```
sudo jupyter serverextension enable --py ipyparallel
sudo jupyter nbextension install --py ipyparallel
sudo jupyter nbextension enable --py ipyparallel
```

Don't forget to start it by :

```
ipcluster start
```

Answer (score 0):

That suggests that `ipcluster` doesn't point to the version you expect to have installed. What do you see for:

```
ipcluster --version
```

? You might also check if there's more than one installed with:

```
which -a ipcluster
```

You can also verify that the `ipcluster` command is started with the Python you expect with:

```
head -n 1 $(which ipcluster)
```

If there is some confusion of package versions, it can help to remove and reinstall the package. Repeat:

```
pip uninstall ipyparallel
```

Until it says there is no ipyparallel package found, then install again with:

```
pip install --upgrade ipyparallel
```

Comment: Minrk, I did more checks following your tips. But everything looks fine though.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue, try on your terminal :

```
jupyter serverextension enable --py ipyparallel --user
jupyter nbextension install --py ipyparallel --user 
jupyter nbextension enable --py ipyparallel --user
```

It worked just fine for me, I had the same command problem and everything seemed well installed (ipcluster version, python version...).

The issue was also debated on IPython's Github if you need further information : https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel/issues/170